# Dot character '.' in MVC Web API 2 for request such as api/people/STAFF.45287

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

The URL I'm trying to let work is one in the style of: http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff.33311 (just like sites as LAST.FM allow all sort of signs in their RESTFul & WebPage urls, for example "[http://www.last.fm/artist/psy'aviah](http://www.last.fm/artist/psy%27aviah)" is a valid url for LAST.FM).

What works are following scenarios:
- http://somedomain.com/api/people/ - which returns all people
- http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff33311 - would work as well, but it's not what I'm after
I'd want the url to accept a "dot", like the example below
- http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff.33311 - but this gives me a

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I've set up following things:

1. The controller "PeopleController"

   ```
   public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPeople()
   {
       return _people;
   }

   public IHttpActionResult GetPerson(string id)
   {
       var person = _people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id.ToLower().Equals(id.ToLower()));
       if (person == null)
           return NotFound();

       return Ok(person);
   }
   ```
2. The WebApiConfig.cs

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       // Web API configuration and services

       // Web API routes
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```

I already tried following all the tips of this blogpost http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx but it still won't work.. I also think it's quite tedious and I wonder if there isn't another, better and more secure way.

We have our Id's internally like this, so we're going to have to find a solution to fit the dot in one way or another, preferably in the style of "." but I'm open to alternative suggestions for urls if need be...

Comment: Not an answer, but as to *why* your're getting a 404 for http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff.33311 - by default, IIS looks at this URL and sees the . as a file extension and invokes the static file handler, bypassing your MVC API. The answer you accepted (running all managed modules for all requests) works because you force every request to IIS to go through the ASP.NET pipeline (therefore, your controllers)

Comment: Closely related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087246/465053).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Following setting in your `web.config` file should fix your issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: I will try this out asap when I'm back at the office

Comment: It did the trick. Though, are there any vulnerabilities by setting this option? Why isn't this the standard behaviour?

Comment: Ok, for anyone's interest: I see my question above being answered here on the accepted answer at the time of writing (answer by Kapil Khandelwal): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning

Comment: Yes, it worked, bus others, I would like to know which particular module is required for this functionality to work?

Comment: When I tried this, it would only work if I put a '/' at the end of the path. Any suggestions why this is? On a side note, the answer below that specifically adds the 'UrlRoutingModule' instead of running all modules, also worked for me, although still with the issue that it requires a '/' at the end to work.

Comment: I don't need to add the "/" character for it to work.. Website's running under Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/167018 is worth looking at if you are concerned (and rightfully so) about the performance impact of enabling runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.

Comment: @KiranChalla:  Does this work when the app runs under classic mode? It doesn't seem so in my case.

Comment: That solved my issue. I was trying to pass an android app ID via the RESTFul api (br.com.google) and it was not working. Thanks !

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: This should work, but it is a bit overkill. It should be ok for WEB API because you should not have any static resources, but I would not use it for MVC.

Comment: Thank you. This also works for `@` at-sign character in route.

Comment: I *also* had to add a new attribute in web.config system.web/httpRuntime: relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"

Comment: This worked AND ALSO fixed an issue where the Swagger page "Can't read swagger JSON from https://[MACHINE:PORT]/swagger/docs/v1.1" My assumption is that the v.1.1 in the URL was succumbing to the same issue.

Answer (score 151):

Suffix the URL with a slash e.g. `http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff.33311/` instead of `http://somedomain.com/api/people/staff.33311`.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles my answer could be considered more of a workaround than an actual answer, depends on your interpretation of the question.

Comment: That does not work though when the dot is at the end of the URL section as in /people/member.

Comment: If the input isn't simple, perhaps an odata style query suffix is more suitable that a rest URL.

Comment: No, what if I don't want a slash at the end?! It should _not_ be required.

Comment: @JoshM. This is a workaround, I didn't write ASP.NET. Also, the slash doesn't affect the request. It does, however, help make your intentions more clear as in `google.com/my query goes here/` vs. `google.com/subDomain my query goes here`.

Comment: This is best answer. No need to change in web.config. Upvote

Comment: Really love this answer. After spending a day looking at a variety of routing options in WebApi, this solution just is so simple, it is beautiful.

Comment: @JoshM. - it's not ideal, yes. What i did was just add an 'endpoint' to the url, so instead of something like `analytes/method/2008.(w)/` i have `analytes/method/2008.(w)/detail`. That way requests with a dot in them still work and i don't have that trailing slash hanging out like it doesn't belong. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Yes this is the best you shouldn't have to modify the web.config.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Maybe some breaking changes in WebAPI

Answer (score 38):

I've found that **adding** the following **before** the standard `ExtensionlessUrlHandler` solves the issue for me:

```xml
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0-ForApi"
     path="api/*"
     verb="*"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

I don't think the name actually matters all that much except it probably helps if your IDE (Visual Studio in my case) is managing your site configuration.

H/T to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802305/264628

Comment: I added it 'after' the standard line and it also worked fine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Does not require / at end of uri

Comment: Thanks for the BEFORE, because it wasn't working after!

Comment: I believe the modules run in order of declaration, so always put more specific (or more important) ones before more generic ones.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know what I am doing really, but after playing with the previous answer a bit I came up with another, perhaps more appropriate, solution:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also don't know what it is doing but it looks better than the other solution.

Comment: appears to move the url routing module (which is what's catching that the request includes an extension and then tries to handle it as a file) to the end of the list of modules, which is sufficient to put it after the module handling the api request.  IMHO, this is the best workaround available from the ones I've seen on SO, at least [ATTOW](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/ATTOW)

Comment: It isn't the relocation to the end of the list, it's the removal of the default precondition that this module only run for managed handlers.  The default config uses this format:
`<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />`

Comment: Thanks - that would explain the behavior.

Answer (score 13):

I found that I needed to do more than just set the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute to `true`. I also had to ensure that the extensionless URL handler was configured to look at all paths. In addition, there is one more bonus configuration setting you can add which will help in some cases. Here is my working Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"  path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Note, specifically, that the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0` has its `path` attribute set to `*` as opposed to `*.` (for instance).

Comment: I just got bit by the `path="*."`. Just curious, what is the reason people set that to `path="*."`?

Comment: Actually, I changed it to `path="*"` and had a problem because we're hosting a documentation site side by side with our WebAPI and that site had problems with .jpg, .png, and other files with extensions.

Comment: @JustinP8 Did you also set `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` ? That should make .NET handle those static files.

Comment: Yes. I wound up doing that. I don't really like that though because now all the static files go through the .NET pipeline. Luckily, as this is a webAPI service, only the Swagger and Swashbuckle stuff for the API docs/helper site are affected.

Comment: i found this broke all static file requests. error 500. I had runAllManaged... set to true.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use this in Web.config file:

```
<add name="ManagedSpecialNames" path="api/people/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

before standard "ExtensionlessUrlHandler".

For instance in my case I put it here:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ManagedFiles" path="api/people/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

So you force URLs of such pattern to be managed by you, instead of standard management as files in application directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck in this situation but appending `/`
 at the end of URL wasn't look clean for me.

so just add below in **web.config** `handlers` tag
 and you will be good to go.

```
<add name="Nancy" path="api" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" allowPathInfo="true" />
```

Comment: Can you explain what Nancy is and whether it is a library to be included in the project? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that both way works for me: either setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true or add ExtentionlessUrlHandler as following. Finally i choose to add extensionUrLHandler since runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests do have performance impact to the site.

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" 
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this issue. I was under a circumstance where I was not supposed to play with IIS and website config related settings. So I had to make it working by making changes at the code level only.

The point is that the most common case where you would end up having dot character in the URL is when you get some input from the user and pass it as a query string or url fragment to pass some argument to the parameters in the action method of your controller.

```
public class GetuserdetailsbyuseridController : ApiController
{
     string getuserdetailsbyuserid(string userId)
     {
        //some code to get user details
     }
}
```

Have a look at below URL where user enters his user id to get his personal details:

```
http://mywebsite:8080/getuserdetailsbyuserid/foo.bar
```

Since you have to fetch some data from the server we use http `GET` verb. While using `GET` calls any input parameters can be passed only in the URL fragments.

So to solve my problem I changed the http verb of my action to `POST`. Http `POST` verb has the facility of passing any user or non-user input in body also. So I created a JSON data and passed it into the body of the http `POST` request:

```
{
  "userid" : "foo.bar"
}
```

Change your method definition as below:

```
public class GetuserdetailsbyuseridController : ApiController
{
     [Post]
     string getuserdetailsbyuserid([FromBody] string userId)
     {
        //some code to get user details
     }
}
```

**Note**: More on when to use `GET` verb and when to use `POST` verb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46585/465053).

Comment: Not an appropriate solution if you're building a REST API.