# DefaultInlineConstraintResolver Error in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web API 2 and I'm getting the following error when I send a POST to my API method using IIS 7.5 on my local box.

```
The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'string'.

Line 21: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

None of my APIs work using IIS. However, I'm able to run my API project in Visual Studio using IIS Express and successfully make a POST to my login API, but when I try and make a GET request to another API call, I get the constraint resolver error.

In order to troubleshoot this, I created a brand new Web API 2 project in Visual Studio and started importing the existing APIs into the new project one at a time and running them to ensure they work. Using IIS Express with this new project, I get the same exact results as I did with my existing API project.

What am I missing here? Even with a brand new project I'm not able to make GET requests without running into this constraint resolver issue.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

The error means that somewhere in a Route, you specified something like

```
[Route("SomeRoute/{someparameter:string}")]
```

"string" is not needed as it is the assumed type if nothing else is specified.

As the error indicates, the `DefaultInlineConstraintResolver` that Web API ships with does not have an inline constraint called `string`. The default supported ones are the following:

```
// Type-specific constraints
{ "bool", typeof(BoolRouteConstraint) },
{ "datetime", typeof(DateTimeRouteConstraint) },
{ "decimal", typeof(DecimalRouteConstraint) },
{ "double", typeof(DoubleRouteConstraint) },
{ "float", typeof(FloatRouteConstraint) },
{ "guid", typeof(GuidRouteConstraint) },
{ "int", typeof(IntRouteConstraint) },
{ "long", typeof(LongRouteConstraint) },

// Length constraints
{ "minlength", typeof(MinLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "maxlength", typeof(MaxLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "length", typeof(LengthRouteConstraint) },

// Min/Max value constraints
{ "min", typeof(MinRouteConstraint) },
{ "max", typeof(MaxRouteConstraint) },
{ "range", typeof(RangeRouteConstraint) },

// Regex-based constraints
{ "alpha", typeof(AlphaRouteConstraint) },
{ "regex", typeof(RegexRouteConstraint) }
```

Comment: That makes sense why I was seeing the errors. I had {string:type} in my route attribute. I removed it and it's working now.

Comment: Why is string not included??

Comment: @AndreasFurster: Because `string` can't apply any constraint.

Comment: "string" is not needed as it is the assumed type if nothing else is specified.

Comment: Where did you get this list?

Comment: @AndrewGray This list is available here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

Comment: Something to watch out for is if you are trying to use strings that have dots in them as part of attribute routing you'll have to change your config (which has a performance impact) for it to work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287

Comment: In case the problem was because route attribute like: {string:type}, just remove the 'string:'

Comment: If you need you can change the format of the routes

Answer (score 37):

One more thing if you can't use int, bool or any other constraint it is key sensitive and you need to remove any white spaces.

```
//this will work
[Route("goodExample/{number:int}")]
[Route("goodExampleBool/{isQuestion:bool}")]
//this won't work
[Route("badExample/{number : int}")]
[Route("badExampleBool/{isQuestion : bool}")]
```

Comment: You'd think they'd `trim()` these after splitting and before doing a comparison...  Not trimming strings used as keys is a major pet peeve of mine going all the way back to my FoxPro days.

Answer (score 11):

I also got this error when I left a space between the variable name and the variable type in the route, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id: int}", Name = "GetStuff")]
```

It should be the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}", Name = "GetStuff")]
```

Answer (score 2):

I designed a API route for one Undo Web API method and I tried to apply ENUM datatype validation on action in route and encountered below DefaultInlineConstrainResolver Error

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The inline constraint
>   resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to
>   resolve the following inline constraint: 'ActionEnum’

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/orders/undo/{orderID}/action/{actiontype: OrderCorrectionActionEnum}")]
public IHttpActionResult Undo(int orderID, OrderCorrectionActionEnum actiontype)
{
    _route(undo(orderID, action);
}

public enum OrderCorrectionActionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    Cleared,

    [EnumMember]
    Deleted,
}
```

To apply ENUM constrain, you have to create custom `OrderCorrectionEnumRouteConstraint` by using `IHttpRouteConstraint`.

```
public class OrderCorrectionEnumRouteConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        // You can also try Enum.IsDefined, but docs say nothing as to
        // is it case sensitive or not.
        var response = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OrderCorrectionActionEnum)).Any(s = &gt; s.ToLowerInvariant() == values[parameterName].ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        return response;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary&lt; string, object&gt; values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        bool response = Enum.GetNames(typeof(BlockCorrectionActionEnum)).Any(s = &gt; s.ToLowerInvariant() == values[parameterName].ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        return response;              
    }
}
```

Reference (This is my blog): https://rajeevdotnet.blogspot.com/2018/08/web-api-systeminvalidoperationexception.html for more details

Answer (score 2):

You get strings as a type in the following manner

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("users/{name}")]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```

Basically you just don't specify the type

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when Type as declared as string. When I changed that to int it started working

```
[HttpGet][Route("testClass/master/{Type:string}")]
```