# How to use the same route with different parameter types?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an Api controller with two different actions that take different parameter types.

```
    // GET: users/sample%40email.com
    [Route("users/{emailAddress}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string emailAddress)

    // GET: users/1D8F6B90-9BD9-4CDD-BABB-372242AD9960
    [Route("users/{reference}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserByReference(Guid reference)
```

Problem is multiple actions are found matching when I make a request to either. Looking at other answers I thought I needed to setup routes in the WebApiConfig like so...

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "apiEmail",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{email}"
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "apiReference",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{reference}"
            );
```

What do I need to do so that each action is called based on the parameter type I pass in?

I'm very new to Web.Api any additional explanation text would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do like below method declaration with attribute routing enabled:
//declare method with guid 1st

```
// GET: users/1D8F6B90-9BD9-4CDD-BABB-372242AD9960
[Route("users/{reference:guid}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserByReference(Guid reference)
```

and declare other method like below

```
// GET: users/sample%40email.com
[Route("users/{emailAddress}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(string emailAddress)
```

Please let me know, is this work for you ?

Comment: I get a new error " The inline constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following inline constraint: 'reference' " probably something to do with the WebApiConfig

Comment: @OrbitalFriendshipCannon check below reference: [DefaultInlineConstraintResolver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412021/defaultinlinecontraintresolver-error-in-webapi-2)

Comment: @OrbitalFriendshipCannon Please check WebApiConfig and remove routes which are added for conventional routing.