# Specifying routeTemplate with a URL fragment containing '.' char doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to map an HttpRoute (in Asp.Net Web API) where the incoming URL has '.' character.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
            (
            name: "ReturnPushPackageRule",
            routeTemplate: "v1/pushPackages/web.com.example.test",
            defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Values",
                    action = "ReturnWebsitePackage"
                }
            );
```

I have the definition for the action like the following:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ReturnWebsitePackage()
    {
    .....
}
}
```

but I get a Method not found exception when I hit the URL. I suspect it is because of the URL having '.' char. Has anyone else comes across this and knows how to resolve?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287

Comment: Yep thanks. Adding the following did solve the issue though not sure which particular module enabled this scenario.  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Did you tried the second answer? About UrlRoutingModule?