# Unable to send files to ASP.NET WEB API using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to send file to WEB API using HttpClient and using the below code to achieve it. I couldn't figure out why am not revcieving any files in WEB API, but the request hits the APIcontroller.

**Client Side Code**

```
            var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\SomLocation\ExcelFile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            fs.CopyTo(ms);
            var client = new HttpClient();                
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GetAPIBaseAddress());
            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(ms);
            var data = new MultipartFormDataContent();  
            data.Add(content, "file1");
            var response = client.PostAsync(GetImportAPIURL(), data).Result;
```

**In API**

```
       System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
       foreach(System.Web.HttpPostedFile file in hfc)
       {
           // do some processing;
       }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you better send it as a byte array instead of MultipartFormDataContent

Comment: @FrebinFrancis - I tried sending it as ByteArrayContent but still it is of no use.

Comment: instead of byte array content you can create a model and create a property with datatype byte[] and post value into that byte array

Comment: or if you want to use the current method then refer this link https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/01/10/how-to-post-a-multipart-http-message-to-a-web-service-in-c-and-handle-it-with-java/

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003849/upload-file-using-put-verb-in-asp-net-web-api-2

Comment: It works, Thankyou - @FrebinFrancis