# How to support dots in WebApi2 urls for a pool running in Classic mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-6, asp.net-web-api2

I need to support dots in urls such as `http://myserver/product/find?name=the.product.name` for a pool running in **Classic** mode.

There are good questions and answers here:

- [Dot character '.' in MVC Web API 2 for request such as api/people/STAFF.45287](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287)
- [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis/12151501#12151501)

but none of them work for an application pool running in Classic mode.

I have tried:

1. `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true">...`
2. `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">...`
3. `<handlers><add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/people/*" verb="..." type="System.Web.Handlers.ransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`
4. `<modules>...<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />`

none of them work in Classic.

The only **unacceptable** workaround seem to be to add an trailing `/` if the dot is in the URL or an extra parameter if the dot is in the params:

- `http://myserver/product/find.all/`
- `http://myserver/product/find?name=the.product.name&useless=1`

I cannot switch to Integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to set the correct handler for classicMode

```
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" 
      path="*" 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,OPTIONS" 
      modules="IsapiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" 
      responseBufferLimit="0" />

    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" 
      path="*" 
      verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,OPTIONS" 
      modules="IsapiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
      preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" 
      responseBufferLimit="0" />
  </handlers>
```