# Web API RoutePrefix version issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

When I use the following RoutePrefix, it works

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Home")]
```

But following doesn't

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1.0/Home")]
```

Can't we use ***Versions*** with decimal?

Comment: what happens when you url encode the period to %2E ? for example "api/v1%2E0/Home" ?

Comment: http://abcdefg.com:1300/Help/Api/POST-api-v1.0-Home-MethodName

Comment: I have a feeling that answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287) post may help

Comment: Also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis/12151501) one