# HttpControllerSelector not finding my controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to develop a web application that should respond to URL's like "api/ping.v1" (the URL's are specified externally, no option to change them) and I'm having problems, because the HttpControllerSelector is not finding my controller class. I always get the result 'Not found'.
I don't know, how to configure routing, so that my controller class can be found correctly. Here is some code, what I have done so far:

Controller class:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class PingController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("api/ping.v1")]
        public PingResponse HandleRequest(PingRequest request)
        {
            // TODO: Handle request and create Response object.
            return new PingResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web-API-Konfiguration und -Dienste

            // Web-API-Routen
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

PingRequest.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class PingRequest
    {
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string UserDms { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(7)]
        public string Ipn { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(8)]
        public string DealerId { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(20)]
        public string WorkshopPartshopId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class PingResponse is completely empty, so I don't post this class here.

My HTML page for testing the web application:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Ping Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h2>Ping</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Ping" onclick="ping();" />
    <p id="pingResult"/>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ping() {
        $.post('api/ping.v1',  {userDms: "wb", ipn: "Ipn", dealerId: "dealer", workshopPartshopId: "wshop"})
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#pingResult').text(JSON.stringify(data.response)).css("color", "black");
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#pingResult').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start my web application from Visual Studio I can see my testing site in the browser with the button "Ping". After clicking on the button ping I will get the message "Error: Not found".

I hope someone can point me to the correct direction what I am making wrong with my routing configuration.

Best Regards
Michael

Comment: The problem is not your URL. Its the '.' in your API. It will considered as an extension and use like a static file request.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287

Comment: Why do you repeat my answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by that dot in the Url. IIS considers that Url points to static file and does not even executes routing logic. If you have no option to avoid such Urls, you could change this behavior by adding `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` attribute to `modules` section of `web.config`:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<!-- ... -->
</modules>
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and helpful answer. This entry in web.config solves my problem.