# The resource cannot be found with selected value - WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have set the routing api/Exchange/Groups/Members/{samAccountName} on my web api and is working

But if the value of **samAccountName** contains wording "prn.", It will return *The resource cannot be found*.

Example

http://localhost:4483/api/Exchange/Groups/Members/prn.agency1

http://localhost:4483/api/Exchange/Groups/Members/prn.agency2

http://localhost:4483/api/Exchange/Groups/Members/prn.agency3

I not sure where is wrong. Here is my code snippet

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Exchange/Groups/Members/{samAccountName}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMembers(string samAccountName)
{
   //Query from Exchange       
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Duplicate question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `samAccountName` format - it contains dot, which is interpreted by IIS as a file extension. IIS tries to find handler for file type `*.agency1` (`agency2`, `agency3`), cannot find it and throws an error.

You either should change format to exclude dot, like change it to dash/underscore, or enable this parameter in your `web.config`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Some more information and drawbacks about `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` flag can be found in this blog post: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78

Answer (score 0):

In web.config, add

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

More details explained [here](http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/06/04/web-api-with-dot-in-the-route/).