# Can WebAPI serve static image files for only certain routes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.Net MVC 4.5 WebAPI controller (IIS8) that can serve static images files from a repository. The URLs I want to use are like;

```
 http://example.com/blob/image/123412341324.jpg
```

The trouble is '.jpg' here appears to be going through the static file handler, which for the most part is what I want to keep. I don't want *all* static files to go through ASP.Net just the ones on this URL path.

Is there any way I can configure ASP.Net to serve up these files without `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` and without modifying the url such as removing the file extension? Ideally, an IIS routing mechanism that looked at the folder path `/blob/image/`;

```
 http://example.com/blob/image/123412341324.jpg -- route through ASP.Net WebAPI

 http://example.com/staticimages/123412341324.jpg    -- do not route through ASP.Net
 http://example.com/anywherelese/123412341324.jpg    -- do not route through ASP.Net
```

I know I could write a separate 'IHttpHandler' but I'd like to route it through the MVC WebAPI controller if possible.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this is quite easy to do with handler mappings. I tried a few wildcards but although `*.jpeg` works `blob/image/*.jpeg` does not. Eventually, with a little help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942452/unable-to-map-an-httphandler-to-a-path-wildcard-mapping) I came up with the following entry in my app's web.config which does what I need and routes all requests for this controller;

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
...
        <add name="my-blob-jpeg-ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="blob/image" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
...
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It's not specific to image files but I don't plan on putting any other static content along that path so I'm good.