# How do I run a .exe on Windows webserver (IIS) when a user clicks a link on an html page

Tags: php, html

This is intranet stuff, I'm well aware that this is not secure.

Basically on my server running Windows Server and IIS for web, I have an executable file that I'd like to run remotely with sthe clicks of a button. For example:

Button 1 would run "C:\exe\program.exe arg1 arg2"
Button 2 would run "C:\exe\program.exe arg1 arg3"
and so on and so forth...

Again, this is on a home system that has no connection to the internet whatsoever, so I am not concerned about any cybersecurity threats this may pose.

Everything I can find only explains how to to this to run a local file. I need to run a remote file.

Comment: You can probably write a quick ASP (Classic or .NET) script, or PHP script (since you tagged that) which would respond to the form submission (caused by button click) and then that can in turn run the (presumably command-line?) .exe on the webserver.

Comment: Or try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217677/setting-iis-to-execute-exe-instead-of-downloading